# See if radio button is checked

Tags: angular, typescript

In my HTML, I have a radio button within a form:

```
<mat-radio-button [(ngModel)]="boxChecked" name="boxChecked" value="boxChecked">Check me</mat-radio-button>
```

In my TypeScript, I have my boolean `boxChecked`:

```
boxChecked = false;
```

When I submit my form, I use `console.log(this.boxChecked);` to see if my boolean has changed from `false` to `true`, but it never changes, no matter how many times I click the radio button.

I have tried to research and most people say, that having a boolean and binding it with ngModel should be enough to connect my boolean to my radio-button, and it should be changed everytime I click it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You should use checkbox in your case like this -

```
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="boxChecked"> boxChecked </mat-checkbox>
```

PS: Radio button is always used in case of we have more than one option and we need to let user select one among them.

But if you still want to use radio button then you should need to bind value to `radio-group`, demo example -

```
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  [(ngModel)]="boxChecked">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="boxChecked">
    {{season}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

[Documentation Link](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples)

Comment: Sorry. but it's not working for some reason. In your Documentation Link, `[value]` is bound to `season` which is something not defined in the TS-file, whereas I try to bind `[value]` to the boolean defined in my TS. Nonetheless, the boolean isn't changed. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: No, season is local variable of the `*ngFor` in the documentation, please check that

Comment: It doesn't work though, you are welcome to try in own IDE. Sorry and thanks

Comment: Bro its official documentation page and I have checked too its working fine, probably you need to tweek your code a bit to make it working.

Comment: Yes but they set the `[value]` to `season` (not defined as a string in TS), whereas I set it to `boxChecked` (defined as boolean in TS). I know season is a local variable for `seasons` but it's still a difference. I also tried with just your example plain and none of my code - and still doesn't work. I will let you know if I find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have made it clear about the usage of `mat-radio-button`. Coming to the problem in your code, it is mainly due to:

```
<mat-radio-button [(ngModel)]="boxChecked" name="boxChecked" 
                value="boxChecked" <<-- here lies the problem
>Check me</mat-radio-button>
```

your `boxChecked` variable is already set to `false` in your `Typescript` Code. What `Angular` is doing is assigning the value provided in `value` field to the variable provided in `ngModel` field.

Ultimately your `boxChecked`(in `ngModel`) variable gets `boxChecked(false)` (in `value`).

If you want to see a change in value try using this:

```
<mat-radio-button [(ngModel)]="boxChecked" name="boxChecked" 
                value="true" 
>Check me</mat-radio-button>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not working for some reason. Appreciate the help though.